# Error response from daemon: CreateComputeSystem

Tags: docker

So I have created a public docker image that I have pulled down to my t2.micro widows machine however when I try start it I get the following error.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker run 83c3c30121b4
C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: CreateComputeSystem ff4cf0b3d769b2634a6215b41ad2d3804bd4376f04612130fdb4b43461a67862: The container operating system does not match the host operating system.
(extra info: {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"ff4cf0b3d769b2634a6215b41ad2d3804bd4376f04612130fdb4b43461a67862","Owner":"docker","VolumePath":"\\\\?\\Volume{fd2a1d65-55e2-4950-a679-adba0463371b}","IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\ff4cf0b3d769b2634a6215b41ad2d3804bd4376f04612130fdb4b43461a67862","Layers":[{"ID":"d1347cf8-7dfe-5f25-8e78-1dca1f6a13f2","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\397eb7e4ca157aa9f7269ba118acb9820870a2c3abbcf4294f4e8ba3a737ed6f"},{"ID":"15f958f5-601e-5ec1-8709-200336f00753","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\6dea34870f4da63ce0000f0ff5d69c9b6e62d2ff1d5ec33833cba14d27d2f7a8"},{"ID":"c4ec13c2-539d-5212-8075-ca9032868737","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\346021c8247cc5873d79630eb977de344f86be08cc39779410a072480e617d5c"},{"ID":"53b75035-7608-575d-a014-c889bdbc7178","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\0a04e0ae33221d67365c6e035cb67a600c94c2f153fdc1964b4c02f7c802ce5c"},{"ID":"88ca624e-3e5f-525d-9701-f81622e169c7","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\e8396564261287ab361c109f5fbbdf4fff5827b946354ca0ea6f62191b0a2710"},{"ID":"edb922ce-42c0-51e5-a5a4-fc02a575b2e9","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\b3377f8ab200af4bf5560455605a6b54e0661c10cccb7054a4886757bdf3c1aa"},{"ID":"8accabbc-6536-597d-a08c-2f4329daec30","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\c666f98497083c74650bb4182afa8dd962e6371c0565eb32f784ee6782fc3617"},{"ID":"0c516134-cbd4-5728-a0b0-f01aa89f40d7","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\9daa49c1d914e8271b9e9d9138066435268bf31830f5345f8bbf47bf83890bb5"},{"ID":"817933cf-c1f7-5d82-ba09-d421591b8937","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\2265c94b17a4db781bc465df8f8d75e61ce889474b1d08690d8ccfa6c8c1f55a"},{"ID":"41b5c9df-0b8d-5b06-abb9-dce88f5eabfa","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\24ba82f803a789de671fd3f4e66f1aa3a64a6d1e15015be0f3e55813bf2c881a"},{"ID":"08ef04c6-ba9c-55df-bdce-a313054351dc","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\aeba860f7c33229ce4705a7d487fc583309295acf14332bf43c25a154b9d6d82"},{"ID":"b70cf733-3596-57b3-8295-766771c9cbe4","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\7e2f306cd1af30c3d347bf26942c4d02e6e21e222c87d0476bd45e601abc3169"}],"HostName":"ff4cf0b3d769","HvPartition":false,"EndpointList":["F632D99D-7CA2-4492-A6E0-877B4C6D4BED"],"AllowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true}).
```

I just used the default docker file that visual studio creates. I have also opened port 80 on the EC2.

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  decodelicense:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}decodelicense
    build:
      context: .\DecodeLicense
      dockerfile: Dockerfile


FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-1803
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
```

Please let me know what could cause this and what logs I should look at.

My Machine:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           18.09.2
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        6247962
 Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:12:31 2019
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.2
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       6247962
  Built:            Sun Feb 10 04:28:48 2019
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

On the server:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Enterprise
 Version:           18.09.6
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        1578dcadd2
 Built:             05/04/2019 02:34:11
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Enterprise
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.6
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.10.8
  Git commit:       1578dcadd2
  Built:            05/04/2019 02:32:24
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Comment: The error message says `The container operating system does not match the host operating system.` What is the OS of the container? What is the OS of the Amazon EC2 instance you are using?

Comment: This is the compatibility list between win dockers and their hosts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility

Comment: @aran Where do I check this? What command can I use to validate that I have the right containers.